# How to get ACF repeater filed values one by one?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I am using ACF pro repeater filed to create a table list. I want to get each row separately.

How can I get each row's value separately?

Here's my code:

```
<?php if( have_rows('depleted_nutrients', 153) ):
        while( have_rows('depleted_nutrients', 153) ): the_row(); ?>

             <?php the_sub_field('depleted_nutrient'); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: I never had problems with it, but `have_rows()` seems to have it's issues, ie: https://wpml.org/forums/topic/acf-have_rows-returns-false-on-translated-page-but-true-on-default-language/

Answer (score 0):

For some reason your example never worked for me either - its ACF recommended... (weird).

I always use method below - call objects and then call each individual object and get its parameters.

```
$rows = get_field('repeater_field_name');
if($rows)
{
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
        echo '<li>sub_field_1 = ' . $row['sub_field_1'] . ', sub_field_2 = ' . $row['sub_field_2'] .', etc</li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Source: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/